# Angular Dropdown Not Displaying Text

Tags: angular, typescript, components

I'm trying to display an array of `KeyValue` items in a `p-dropdown` angular component. It's picking up the correct amount of data (5) but it's not displaying any text in the dropdown ?

[image]

**key-value.ts**

```
export interface KeyValue {
    label: string;
    value: string;
}
```

**dd.json**

```
{ 
  "Domains": [
    {"label": "North America (NAM)", "value": "NAM"}, 
    {"label": "Europe (EUR)", "value": "EUR"}, 
    {"label": "Australia (AUS)", "value": "AUS"}, 
    {"label": "Latin America (LAAM)", "vaule": "LAAM"}, 
    {"label": "Asia (APA)", "value": "APA"}
  ]
}
```

**component.html**

```
<div class="container">
  <div>Domain:<span class="required">*</span></div>
  <p-dropdown [options]="domains" formControlName="domain" optionLabel="text" (onChange)="dataChanged($event, 'domain')" placeholder="Select an option"></p-dropdown>
  <br>
</div>
```

**component.ts**

```
import { KeyValue } from '../../model/key-value';

export class RequestComponent implements OnInit {
  domains:  KeyValue[] = [];

  constructor(private service: Service) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.getPageData();
  }

  getPageData() {
    console.log("getPageData() First: " + this.domains);
    this.service.getDomains().subscribe(domains => {console.log("getPageData() Second: " + domains); this.domains = domains});
    console.log("getPageData() Third: " + this.domains);
  }
}
```

**service.ts**

```
@Injectable()
export class Service{

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  getDomains(): Observable<any> {
    return this.getJSON()
      .pipe(
        map(
          data => { data.Domains;
                    console.log("getDomains(): " + data.Domains); } ));}

  getJSON(): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.get("assets/dd.json");
  }
}
```

**Console Messages**

```
getPageData() First: 
getPageData() Third: 
getDomains(): [object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object]
getPageData() Second: undefined
```

**EDIT**

I've made an update to the `getDomains()` method and added an extra return:

```
getDomains(): Observable<any> {
  return this.getUNPProperties().pipe(map(data => { console.log("getDomains(): " + data.Domains); return data.Domains}));
}
```

The console messages are as follows:

```
getPageData() First: 
getPageData() Third: 
getDomains(): [object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object]
getPageData() Second: [object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object]
```

Comment: It looks like nothing is being returned from `getDomains()` method.. but this was suggested by someone else as a working solution ?

Comment: So why aren't you returning from `getDomains()`

Comment: See edits @xyz -- I thought the first return would have returned it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please set the `optionLabel` property to `'label'`. By default **PrimeNg** dropdown will take `label` as display-field and `value` for value-field. by changing the `optionLabel` to `'text'` will look for a field with name `text` and which is not available in the `domains` list.

So the Updated code for `p-dropdown` is below.

```
<p-dropdown 
   [options]="domains" 
   formControlName="domain" 
   optionLabel="label" 
   (onChange)="dataChanged($event, 'domain')" 
   placeholder="Select an option">
</p-dropdown>
```

Comment: You absolute HEROOOOOOOOOOOOOOOO! I've been looking at this for hours (it's copy pasta from another project).. THANK YOU